# How to use custom predef for all files in project

Tags: scala, import

I'd like to shadow some Predef members and introduce my own realization for them. How can I inform compiler that my.own.Predef._ should be imported instead of scala.Predef._ ?

Answer (score 4):

One way I've seen this done is through chained package clauses.

If the file at `my/own/package.scala` has, for example:

```
package my
package object own {
  type ISeq[+A] = IndexedSeq[A]
  val ISeq = IndexedSeq
}
```

Then any file in the package `my.own` or a subpackage of `my.own` will automatically import `ISeq` as if it came from `Predef`, **IF** you change your package declaration at the top of the file from

```
package my.own.foo
```

to

```
package my.own
package foo
```

The latter form is called a [chained package clause](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/package-clauses/packageclauses.html).

[This article](http://hseeberger.github.io/blog/2013/10/25/attention-seq-is-not-immutable/) (which uses chained package to change `Seq` to use the immutable interface) seems to indicate that you can shadow members in `scala.Predef` this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to update the package line of every file to use this, moving to package chaining which isn't a best practice, so you might as well just add the import for `immutable.Seq`.